# Display chart values in Achartengine

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using the achartengine to make a line graph. The graph is drawn correctly but the display value in top of the point are completely different. The correct point in the y axis is 173.011 but the display value is 158691406. Why the value are different? I am using achartengine0.6.

Comment: If you're still having problems, you should give us some code to check.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to upgrade to AChartEngine 1.0.0.